# Downloading file from server for user logged in as guest

Tags: c#, asp.net, download, forms-authentication

I have a code which allows you to download any file from server to your local host.

This code works fine when i log in as administrator but when i log in as guest user it does not let me download.. and i get an error message saying..

> External component has thrown an exception. 
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

```
 Exception Details: System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException: External component has thrown an exception.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
```

My code is as follows

```
string filepath = restoredFilename.ToString();

            // Create New instance of FileInfo class to get the properties of the file being downloaded
            FileInfo myfile = new FileInfo(filepath);

            // Checking if file exists
            if (myfile.Exists)
            {

                // Clear the content of the response
                Response.ClearContent();

                // Add the file name and attachment, which will force the open/cancel/save dialog box to show, to the header
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + myfile.Name);

                //Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" + myfile.Name);
                // Add the file size into the response header
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", myfile.Length.ToString());

                // Set the ContentType
                Response.ContentType = ReturnExtension(myfile.Extension.ToLower());

                //// Write the file into the response (TransmitFile is for ASP.NET 2.0. In ASP.NET 1.1 you have to use WriteFile instead)
                Response.TransmitFile(myfile.FullName);

                // End the response
                Response.End();
            }
```

I have to download the file using guest.. please help thanks

Stack Trace:

```
[SEHException (0x80004005): External component has thrown an exception.]
   xyzgui.Guest.DriveContents.RestoreOneFileForGUI(Int32 machineID_Download, Int64 fileID, StringBuilder restoredFilename, UInt32 restoredFilenameBufsize) +0
   xyzgui.Guest.DriveContents.file_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\jagmit\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\xyzgui\xyzgui\Guest\DriveContents.aspx.cs:341
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.OnClick(EventArgs e) +111
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +79
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +175
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1565
```

Comment: Your error message says: *Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.* So, can you show us "the exception stack trace below"?

Comment: Are NTFS permissions on your virtual folder ok?

Comment: Where is "the exception stack trace below".

Answer (score 0):

What authentication mechanism are you using: Forms, or Windows?

Do you have impersonation turned on?

I believe that the error you are seeing is generally thrown when there's a security issue - which sounds likely when you say "when I log in as administrator".

Is there more to the method `RestoreOneFileForGUI` that we're not seeing - because it looks like something is throwing a security exception outside of .NET - if it was as simple as the guest account (the account the website is running under) not having access to the file path then you'd see a standard `SecurityException` or `UnauthorizedException` from the [FileInfo constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.fileinfo.aspx).